# Execute an Oracle stored procedure from a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored proc that needs to send information to an Oracle stored proc.

How do I set this up? Should it be a linked server? And how do I write the code to pass and execute the stored proc?

Comment: You say **SQL** (Structured Query Language) but you really mean **SQL Server** (the Microsoft relational database system) - right?? Oracle works with SQL too - and so does IBM DB2, Informix, Firebird, MySQL - you name it.....

Comment: Right, SQL Server (I'm assuming you edited that for me) :)

Comment: I assumed that's what you meant - so yes, I updated your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I ended up having to use Microsofts CLR and write my own little C# application in order to handle the variables being pushed between the servers. Here's what I did:

1. C# Application starts on a scheduled task in windows
2. Application executes the SQL Server stored procedure and gets the return values
3. Application then executes the Oracle stored procedure with appropriate values

Answer (score 8):

a procedure "TestingProcedure" in Oracle server.

a linked Server "LinkedServer" in SQL Server.

call TestingProcedure in SQL server example:

```
EXECUTE ('begin TestingProcedure; end;') AT LinkedServer;
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use:

```
DECLARE @outputParameter int
EXEC ('BEGIN <procedureName>(?,?); END;', @inputParameter , @outputParameter OUTPUT) at <linkedServerName>
```

This allows capturing output parameters

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax that I would probably try from the start:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(<linked server name>, '{CALL <oracle sp>}')
```

What I've seen (I have not tried this myself) is that you can also use `OPENQUERY` to call an Oracle function which can then call the stored procedure, or you can turn the stored procedure into a function. Your connection from SQL Server would then look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(<linked server name>, 'SELECT <oracle function> FROM dual')
```

Comment: So, let me throw another wrench in there, I'll be executing a sproc on Oracle that receives input parameters from me and has an output parameter that I need to capture... what syntax do I use?

Comment: use the syntax in my answer to get the output parameter.